# How to run php file in javascript without using ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to run a php file in javascript when the user refreshes or leaves the page. I'm using a window.onbeforeunload function so if I use ajax, the php file would run without the page reloading. That means the php file would run even when a modal pops up and I don't want that. So I want the php file to run when the user refreshes or leaves the page.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
          $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: 'myfile.php',
                  success: function(response){

                  }
                });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla Javascript have no access to filesystem, you can't run php from it.

Using ajax just allows you to get text content from specified url, same result you can get, when put this url in your browser.

Comment: This is inaccurate. Ajax works both ways...sending and receiving. Also if it is  POST you can't create that in address bar yourself

Comment: @charlietfl of course,  thanks for your addition, i not meant example in the question